# How to get uncommon column values associated with two different rows in a MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query a table with millions of rows using PHP not SQL.

Select B from table where A=1 & C=1 & not present wherever A=2

In the example table the requested B value is 5.

I want to get a value from  column B with a column A value of 1 and column C value of 1 if this column B value is not also present  where column A value is 2.

Thanks.

```
Table
+-+-+-+
|A|B|C|
+-+-+-+
|1|3|0|
+-+-+-+
|1|6|0|
+-+-+-+
|1|5|1|
+-+-+-+
|2|3|1|
+-+-+-+
|2|4|1|
+-+-+-+
|3|3|0|
+-+-+-+
```

Comment: By your logic, it also seems that `B = 3` should be a match.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. 3 cannot be a match because 3 is present in both A-1 and A-2. I am searching for B values uncommon in both A-1 and A-2 where C =1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT B FROM(
select B, COUNT(B) CNT
from test
WHERE A IN (1,2)
GROUP BY B)X WHERE CNT=0 OR CNT=1;
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with PHP not SQL. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I want to get a value from  column B with a column A value of 1 and column A value of 1 if this  column B value is not also present in column B where column A value is 2. In the example table the requested B value is 5.